# Add L2 Regularization to Tensorflow contrib.learn.Estimator

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I want to add L2 regularization to a custom contrib.learn estimator and I can't figure out how to do it easily.

Is there a way to add L2 regularization to the existing Estimators (e.g. the DNNClassfier) that I have overlooked?

The only way I could think of adding the L2 norm to my custom estimator is to write a new head with and altered cost function. But I guess there is an easier and more elegant solution to this common problem. Did anybody had the same issue?

EDIT: I guess I found a solution. I can use the gradient_clip_norm to clip the gradients. That way the gradients should be limited by the global L2 Norm and essentially I have L2 regularization. Is my thinking correct?

Comment: As far as I know you can use `l2_regularization_strength` argument in [classifier](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/DNNClassifier) initialization. Does that help?

Comment: I have seen this, but this only works with the ProximalAdagradOptimizer (tf.version 1.0.1), but not with any other. I'm not familiar with this optimizer. I'm currently reading the paper to check if this is an alternative for me.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you cannot incorporate l1 or l2 regularizations on provided estimators, like the subclasses of `tf.estimator.Estimator` and `tf.contrib.learn.Estimator`. Nonetheless, you could create customized `estimator`s by using `tf.layers` api, explained here: https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/estimators. With customized `estimator` you could apply the regularizers. Please refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44238354/4206988 for regularizing weights using `tf.layers` api. Functions like `tf.layers.dense()` has a `kernel_regularizer` field where you can regularize the weight matrix.

And please note that L2 regularization is not the same thing as gradient norm clipping. In norm clipping, there is a specific limit to the norm of the parameter of interest, while in L2 regularization, there is no such limit, it is a soft constraint.