# Add L2 regularization when using high level tf.layers

Tags: tensorflow

Is it possible to add an L2 regularization when using the layers defined in tf.layers?

It seems to me that since tf.layers is an high level wrapper, there is no easy way to get access to the filter weights.

**With tf.nn.conv2d**

```
regularizer = tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(scale=0.1)

weights = tf.get_variable(
    name="weights",
    regularizer=regularizer
)

#Previous layers

...

#Second layer 
layer 2 = tf.nn.conv2d(
input,
weights,
[1,1,1,1],
[1,1,1,1])

#More layers
...

#Loss
loss = #some loss

reg_variables = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.REGULARIZATION_LOSSES)
reg_term = tf.contrib.layers.apply_regularization(regularizer, reg_variables)
loss += reg_term
```

**Now what would that look like with tf.layers.conv2d?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can pass them into [`tf.layers.conv2d` as arguments:](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/conv2d)

```
regularizer = tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(scale=0.1)
layer2 = tf.layers.conv2d(
    inputs,
    filters,
    kernel_size,
    kernel_regularizer=regularizer)
```

Then you should add the regularization loss to your loss like this:

```
l2_loss = tf.losses.get_regularization_loss()
loss += l2_loss
```

*Edit: Thanks Zeke Arneodo, Tom and srcolinas I added, the last bit on your feedback so that the accepted answer provides the complete solution.*

Comment: Do I need to add regularizer to the last loss layer? Like `loss_new = loss_old + regularizer`

Comment: @TYL did you add it to the last loss layer or not?

Comment: Could you expand your answer a bit?

Comment: @thigi I’ve not realized it, theoritically it should be added to the last loss.

Comment: could you add a bit more detail to this answer? It seems correct but doesn't help people struggling with understanding the code

Comment: It seems in tensorflow, you add the regularization loss back to the total loss. But how come the same practice isn't carried out in Keras? Is it doing something else on the backend? For instance, consider this notebook: https://www.kaggle.com/c/cifar-10/discussion/40237

Answer (score 16):

Isn't the answer in your question? You can also use tf.losses.get_regularization_loss (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/losses/get_regularization_loss), which will collect all the REGULARIZATION_LOSSES.

```
...
layer2 = tf.layers.conv2d(input, 
     filters, 
     kernel_size,                        
     kernel_regularizer= tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(scale=0.1))
...
l2_loss = tf.losses.get_regularization_loss()
loss += l2_loss
```

Answer (score 4):

I see two incomplete answers, so here is the complete one:

```
regularizer = tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(scale=0.1)
    layer2 = tf.layers.conv2d(
        inputs,
        filters,
        kernel_size,
        kernel_regularizer=regularizer)
```

alternatively:

```
layer2 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs, 
     filters, 
     kernel_size,                        
     kernel_regularizer= tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(scale=0.1))
```

don't forget to add it to the final loss:

```
l2_loss = tf.losses.get_regularization_loss()
....
loss += l2_loss
```

Basically, add regularization when defining a layer and then make sure you add regularization loss to your loss.

Answer (score 2):

In eager execution, there are two ways.

1. Calculate by hand with `tf.add_n([tf.square(i) for i in layer.variables]) * l2_coef`
   .
2. Using `layer.losses` when the layer is created with `kernel_regularizer`.

As shown in the official examples: [densenet_test.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/eager/python/examples/densenet/densenet_test.py)

```
rand_input = tf.random_uniform((10, 3, 32, 32))
weight_decay = 1e-4

conv = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
    3, (3, 3),
    padding='same',
    use_bias=False,
    kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(weight_decay))

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1)
conv(rand_input)  # Initialize the variables in the layer

def compute_true_l2(vs, wd):
  return tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(vs)) * wd

true_l2 = compute_true_l2(conv.variables, weight_decay)
keras_l2 = tf.add_n(conv.losses)
self.assertAllClose(true_l2, keras_l2)

with tf.GradientTape() as tape_true, tf.GradientTape() as tape_keras:
  loss = tf.reduce_sum(conv(rand_input))
  loss_with_true_l2 = loss + compute_true_l2(conv.variables, weight_decay)
  loss_with_keras_l2 = loss + tf.add_n(conv.losses)

true_grads = tape_true.gradient(loss_with_true_l2, conv.variables)
keras_grads = tape_keras.gradient(loss_with_keras_l2, conv.variables)
self.assertAllClose(true_grads, keras_grads)
```